# C++ Can't Write 1's To Struct Member

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, struct, bit

I'm having a little problem writing 1's to a struct's member.

I have a struct which represents a Voxel which can have 8 children (IDs 0-7). In order to state which children a Voxel has I'm using an unsigned 8-bit integer. If the Voxel has a certain child, then the bit at the position in the children member that equals the child's ID is set to 1.

For example, if a Voxels children member stored the value:
10000101
Then the Voxel would have children 0, 2 and 7 (from right to left).

The code for the Voxel struct is as below:

```
typedef struct Voxel {
       uint8_t children; //list of children
       Voxel* firstChildPointer;
};
```

First child pointer points to the start of a list of voxels which are this voxels children.

The problem occurs when wanting to add a child. I need to change the children member to reflect the added child. When doing this however, I get a runtime exception saying "Access violation writing location" followed by a memory address.

The code I use to change the children is below:

```
void addVoxel(Voxel* parent, char childID) {
       parent->children |= (1 << childID); }
```

When all the Voxels are first loaded into memory the Voxel's children is set without error.
But after that I cannot write 1's to the member. 0's write perfectly fine. I have tried using many methods to write things, even a plain old assignment to a number. But if the number has more 1's then it won't work.

It so happens that a pointer to the parent in this case it stored as a global variable, and each voxel also stores a pointer to it's children, could this be the problem? If so would passing the parent as a reference help? I know how to do this in C# but not in C++.

Any help would be great.

S.

EDIT:

The add voxel method is called using this line:

```
addVoxel(octree, 4);
```

octree is a voxel pointer as defined by:

```
Voxel* octree = octreeLoader.loadVoxelData();
```

The load voxel data method loads octree information from a file. We know that this section and the return pointer work as we use an exact duplicate of them to ray trace. However in short the pointer is created using this line:

```
Voxel* octree;
```

And then assigned memory using this line:

```
octree = (Voxel *) calloc(1, sizeof(Voxel));
```

Children is then assigned using this line:

```
octree[0].children = children;
```

Each further child is then created and given memory in the same way. I have checked the children member is initialised correctly and the childID is correct.

Comment: How do you call the function? Sounds like `parent` is an invalid pointer.

Comment: I call it using this line:

addVoxel(octree, 4);

octree is just a pointer to a voxel. The first Voxel in the tree

Comment: What Martinho said - "parent" is likely corrupt.

Comment: Well I use the same method in things such as a remove voxel method and all works fine, as I don't have to set a value to 1.

Comment: You should post a full, minimal code sample that demonstrates the problem. Also, when I get bad bugs like this, I'll write funcitons to dump/print the state of all my objects so I can see when the point of corruption happens.

Comment: The code above seems OK. I suspect that the problem is parent pointer. To move forward, I would use the debugger at this point.

Comment: I will edit the question. But know that error logging is hard in this program as it goes in and out of the GPU a lot. Though that side should not effect this problem.

Comment: Please check edits an the bottom, and included changes to voxel structure

Answer (score 1):

Somehow your parent pointer is invalid. Changing numbers cannot cause an access violation otherwise. I guess you use these indices to traverse the tree? You should try a tool like valgrind. It may make debugging easier.

Comment: Well I use the same method in things such as a remove voxel method and all works fine, as I don't have to set a value to 1.

Comment: Perhaps you have a dangling pointer and therefore write to a different memory location than you think. This may certainly trigger a crash with certain values. Perhaps not all values since you don't know how that memory is used.

Comment: Unfortunately using references won't magically solve the problem. I think you should try valgrind or Microsoft verifier, depending on platform. If that doesn't give you anything useful you could try putting all valid voxel pointers into a map and before each access validate that it really is a voxel. Then you can trap the error.

Comment: I know that it is pointing to a voxel. I've worked with the same pointer. For example, if I change the |= to a &= it doesn't crash, it effects my program in the expected way from the correct voxel.

Comment: But if parent always points to a valid voxel, that operation cannot cause an access violation.

Comment: You'd think so. I'd think so. But it does. If I write 0's to the same voxel, it works perfectly.

Comment: If you write 0's, the compiler likely optimizes them out entirely, because "X |= 0" is equivalent to "X".  You really need to post a full minimal example that replicates the issue.

Comment: I have tried using different operators though, I can set a 1 bit to 0 no problem. I don't think more code will help. It's all there. I load the octree, then call the addVoxel method on it. It's not in any context that I haven't shown, it's not part of a larger section of code. It's just that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using unsigned char instead of char?  This may not be the problem but it may be compensating for the sign, doing something funky.  You state that &= works, however, AND assignment will will not be assigning values of 1, it will only replace with 0... so it may not crash.  Using the |= is setting to one.  You state 0's work perfectly fine, if that is the case &= will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem reeks of some kind of corruption: especially that you can write zeroes but not ones - that sounds like you're not writing to where you think you're writing to (either some kind of padding or data that for whatever reason is supposed to zero). Either that or you're simply not supposed to be modifying this data in this way after the voxels are initialised.

Do you have all the possible debug checks and guards enabled? The C Runtime can help you out a lot if this is some kind of corruption

If you are already running with all debug options enabled, be aware of the following values when debugging:

```
* 0xABABABAB : Used by Microsoft's HeapAlloc() to mark "no man's land" guard bytes after allocated heap memory
* 0xABADCAFE : A startup to this value to initialize all free memory to catch errant pointers
* 0xBAADF00D : Used by Microsoft's LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED) to mark uninitialised allocated heap memory
* 0xBADCAB1E : Error Code returned to the Microsoft eVC debugger when connection is severed to the debugger
* 0xBEEFCACE : Used by Microsoft .NET as a magic number in resource files
* 0xCCCCCCCC : Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging runtime library to mark uninitialised stack memory
* 0xCDCDCDCD : Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging runtime library to mark uninitialised heap memory
* 0xDEADDEAD : A Microsoft Windows STOP Error code used when the user manually initiates the crash.
* 0xFDFDFDFD : Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging heap to mark "no man's land" guard bytes before and after allocated heap memory
* 0xFEEEFEEE : Used by Microsoft's HeapFree() to mark freed heap memory
```

If you see any of these values being used in place of valid data, something's gone wrong

EDIT: Also, something difficult to ascertain from your question: Is there just voxel data or is there other supporting data - e.g. indices or colour/texture coords of some kind? If writing 1s enabling the children crashes, is it actually that drawing them causes some other data to be used/required? (that for some reason isn't available). Do you get the same crash if you first disable a child writing zero and then later *re*-enable it? Or do you only get crashes from enabling children that didn't exist at all previously?